# Joomla - vhost for admin section of local site

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, xampp, vhosts

How can I setup a vhost to the admin section of a local test site?

Currently I have 2 vhosts:

1. local.testsite.com (localhost/testsite)
2. local.testsite.admin (localhost/testsite/administrator)

Both of which work fine except the admin site won't load properly because it can't find any of the .css or .js resources required to render the page as they are up a level from `localhost/testsite/administrator`

Is there something I can do with .htaccess to solve this?

Comment: Are you able to view home page of site?

Comment: @user2486495 Yes, the admin page is loading too but it can't find the external css and js resources. e.g. `/media/system/js/mootools-core.js` because the media folder is up a level from the site root